# Error: 'dict' object is not callable (Email Validator API)

Tags: python

I have this API URL with a 'GET' method type request:

```
https://api.website.net/?email=[email]&token=[apikey]
```

API Get Request example:

```
https://api.website.net/?email=user@example.com&token=c7747ae4f21d490d8cec41f90a0acdc6
```

API Get Response/Result example:

> {"IsValid":true,"Score":100,"Email":"pat@baltimorewindow.com","State":"Deliverable","Reason":"ACCEPTED EMAIL","Domain":"baltimorewindow.com","Free":false,"Role":false,"Disposable":false,"AcceptAll":false,"Tag":false,"MXRecord":"inbound.registeredsite.com.","EmailAdditionalInfo":[{"Key":"Linkedin","Value":"pat-stout-a0809aa"},{"Key":"Firstname","Value":"pat"},{"Key":"Lastname","Value":"stout"},{"Key":"City","Value":"baltimore"},{"Key":"Country","Value":"united states"},{"Key":"Address","Value":"baltimore, maryland, united states"}]}

So for bulk validation and leads appending i managed to write this code:

```py
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict
from colorama import init
init()
from colorama import Fore,Style

def main():
    fl = open('emails.txt','r')
    data = fl.readlines()
    fl.close()

    key = str(input('Access Key : '))

    for i in data:
        email = i.strip().replace('+','')
        url = f"https://api.website.net/?email={email}&token={key}"
        
        headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
        headers["apikey"] = key
        
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        
        result = response.json()
        if result['State'] == 'Deliverable':
            print(f'{i.strip()} -> {Fore.GREEN+"Valid"+Style.RESET_ALL}')
            fl = open('valid.txt','a')
            fl.write(i.strip()+f'|'+result['MXRecord']+f'|'+'\n')
            fl.close()
        else:
            print(f'{i.strip()} -> {Fore.RED+"Invalid"+Style.RESET_ALL}')
            fl = open('invalid.txt','a')
            fl.write(i.strip()+'\n')
            fl.close()

main()
```

And this is how the outcome in valid.txt looks like (appends the mx records for every valid email):

> "pat@baltimorewindow.com|inbound.registeredsite.com.|"

BUT How can I append the value of the following keys (`Firstname`, `Lastname` and `Address`) so it looks like below in valid.txt:

> "pat@baltimorewindow.com|inbound.registeredsite.com.|pat|stout|baltimore, maryland, united states|"

I tried a few tricks but I keep getting errors like 'dict' object is not callable. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

`Firstname`, `Lastname` and `Address` are not structured the same way as `Email` or `MXRecord` is. They are bounded in a **list** under `EmailAdditionalInfo`, which is at the same level with `MXRecord`. So, accessing `result['EmailAdditionalInfo']` gives you:

```
[
    {
        "Key": "Linkedin",
        "Value": "pat-stout-a0809aa"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Firstname",
        "Value": "pat"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Lastname",
        "Value": "stout"
    },
    {
        "Key": "City",
        "Value": "baltimore"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Country",
        "Value": "united states"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Address",
        "Value": "baltimore, maryland, united states"
    }
]
```

You then have a plenty of ways to extract the fields of interest.

For single use, you can extract them whenever needed:

```
email_addition_info = result['EmailAdditionalInfo']
firstname = [info["Value"] for info in email_addition_info if info["Key"] == "Firstname"][-1]
lastname = [info["Value"] for info in email_addition_info if info["Key"] == "Lastname"][-1]
# ... so on
```

For future reuse (if neccessary), you can convert it into an actual dictionary, like:

```
 {
    "Linkedin": "pat-stout-a0809aa",
    "Firstname": "pat",
    "Lastname": "stout",
    "City": "baltimore",
    "Country": "united states",
    "Address": "baltimore, maryland, united states"
 }
```

Hope it help.